# Является ли результат умножения палиндромом

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector> 
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

bool ili_eto_palindrom_ili_net( int chislo )
{
    bool ok = true;
    vector < char > agaga;
    for ( '  '; chislo; chislo /= 10 )
        agaga.push_back( chislo % 10 );
    for ( unsigned i = 0, j = agaga.size() - 1; i < j; ok = ok && agaga[ i++ ] == agaga[ j-- ] );
    return ok;
}

int main()
{
    int r = -1;
    for ( int x = 999; x; --x )
        for ( int y = x; y; --y )
            if ( ili_eto_palindrom_ili_net( x * y ) )
                r = max ( r, x * y );
    cout << r << endl;
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Прога перемножает два трехзначних числа от 100 до 999 и смотрит, это палиндром или нет. А потом из всех палиндромов находит максимальный. Но когда запускаю, консоль пустая, что не так?

Comment: Возможно, проблема была в том, что в студии `max` - это макрос, который плохо определён.

Comment: Это, кстати, один из доводов в пользу того, что плохо писать `using namespace std;`. Если бы написали `std::max`, то все было бы ОК.

Comment: Теперь я понимаю почему везде пишут именно std::метод, и не юзают using namespace std;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Твой код очень плохо читаем. Лучше явное, чем не явное. + трудности в дебаге
Зацикливается второй цикл в функции. 
Предлагаю заменить функцию вот на эту:

```
bool ili_eto_palindrom_ili_net( int chislo )
{
    vector <int> agaga;
    for ( ; chislo; chislo /= 10 )
        agaga.push_back( chislo % 10 );
    for (int i = 0, j = agaga.size() - 1; i < agaga.size() / 2; i++)
    if (agaga[i] != agaga[j - i]) return false;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: оно то хорошо, но все равно консоль ничего не выдает...

Comment: В чем Вы компилируете? У меня в убунте все нормально собирается и работает.

Comment: VS 2010, компилится все норм но темный экран. Спасибо за помощь! Вопрос решен.

Answer (score 3):

[@enum](/users/6046/enum) ответил в общем правильно. Но я бы написал все-таки немного по-другому. Например, так

```
bool ili_eto_palindrom_ili_net( int chislo )
{
    vector < int > agaga;
    for ( ; chislo; chislo /= 10 )
        agaga.push_back( chislo % 10 );
    for ( int i = 0, j = agaga.size() - 1; i < j; i++, j-- )
        if (agaga[i] != agaga[j] ) return false;    
    return true;
}

int main()
{
    int r = -1, t;
    for ( int x = 999; x >= 100; --x ) {
        for ( int y = x; y >= 100; --y ) {
            t = x*y;
            if ( ili_eto_palindrom_ili_net( t ) )
                r = max ( r, t );
        }
    }
    cout << "Max palindrome: " << r << endl;
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```